# Mathematica: Extract the piece that contains x=0 from within a piecewise function

Tags: expression-manipulation, piecewise

In mathematica, I have a piecewise function similar to:

```
Piecewise[{ {x^2 + 2*x - 4, 0 <= x <= 1/4},
            {0, true}                    }]
```

I don't know how many pieces there will be, or what the internal ordering will look like, but I know that exactly one of the pieces will have `x=0` as its left endpoint. How do I extract that piece in its general form (`x^2 + 2*x - 4`) without knowing the upper end of its domain (`1/4`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given say:

```
expr = Piecewise[{ {x^2 + 2*x - 4, 0 <= x <= 2}, 
                   {0, True}}]
```

... you can convert your `Piecewise` expression back into a list form using:

```
 aa = Internal`FromPiecewise[expr, True]  // Transpose
```

> {{x >= 0 && x <= 2, -4 + 2 x + x^2}, {x > 2 || x < 0, 0}}

Then, you can find the part that corresponds to `x == 0` using:

```
Select[aa, (#[[1]] /. x -> 0) &]
```

> {{x >= 0 && x <= 2, -4 + 2 x + x^2}}

Answer (score 2):

Similar to wolfies' approach - find the part for which the condition is `True` when x->0.

```
p = Piecewise[{{x^2 + 2*x - 4, 0 <= x <= 1/4}, {0, True}}];

Cases[First@p, {e_, c_} /; (c /. x -> 0) :> e]

(* {-4 + 2 x + x^2} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative approach! I'm accepting wolfies' answer mainly for the reason that it deals with the default case better than this one. For example, `Piecewise[{{x^2 + 2*x - 4, 1 <= x <= 2}}]` for x=0 gives {{x > 2 || x < 1, 0}} for wolfies' (indicating the default of 0), but {} for yours (making it a special case to handle).